# Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Tags: php, function, object, format, member

I have an html file which has the following table:

```
<form action="wedding-ajax-support.php" method="get" id="wedding-table">
<table border="0"; align="center">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Key</th>
    <th scope="col">Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="date">Select the date on which your party will take place (mm/dd/yyyy): </label></td>

    <td>
      <input name="date" type="text" class="larger" id="date"  size="12" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="catering">Type the catering grade you would like (from 1 to 5) : </label></td>
    <td><input name="catering" type="text" class="larger" id="catering"  size="5" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="size">Type the number of people you are expecting to attend: </label></td>
    <td><input name="size" type="text" class="larger" id="size"  size="5" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Find me available venues, based on my preferences: </td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="GO!" class="larger" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> One of those inputs is the date. That's the only thing I'm concerned about for now, to keep things simple.
>
> On another file, wedding-ajax-support.php (on which I organize all of my php code) I have this amongst other code:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_GET['date']);
```

$date = $date->format('Y-m-d'); // Changes the format of the date, as the date entered by the user, and the date in the database are of a different format.

> And then a simple echo $date;
>   just to test it.

Then, back at my main file, I put a

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$("#wedding-table").load("wedding-ajax-support.php");

to replace the table with the date in changed format, using ajax via jQuery.

So, when I load my webpage, where the table should have been, a message is displayed 
"Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /disks/diskh/zco/cotm2/public_html/wedding/wedding-ajax-support.php on line 23 Call Stack: 0.0002 333936 1. {main}() /disks/diskh/zco/cotm2/public_html/wedding/wedding-ajax-support.php:0 ".

> Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: don't use a text field for date its asking for trouble, use a calender (script), then you can be suer of the format.

Answer (score 0):

The "GET" variables are setup for PHP by the webserver when they are passed through as query parameters in the URL. In your case, you are loading the page as `"wedding-ajax-support.php"`, so that means that the `_GET` variable is effectively empty.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that the result of

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_GET['date']);
```

is not an instance of `DateTime` but most likely `false` because as [the php doc for DateTime](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php) mentions, `false` will be returned if it cannot create an instance based on the given parameter.

So with

```
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

you are trying to call the method `format()` on `false`, which is no object.

You should find out why `createFromFormat` fails. It could be that `$_GET['date']` is in a format it cannot parse or that it is just empty. Try `var_dump($_GET)` to find out.

As the other answer pointed out, `$_GET` variables are appended to the url, so for `$_GET['date']` to be set the url should look like `wedding-ajax-support.php?date=xyz` for example.

Unfortunately, I did not get what you tried to do with the javascript to help you further.

**Edit: wow this post is very old. Didn't see it before, sorry.**